# Beamer title page extra line space in author

Tags: beamer, titles

getting some extra line space between Prof. DEF GHI and Prof. Jklmno Pqrst in the following beamer latex code. How to solve it?

```
\documentclass[mathserif,10pt,graphics]{beamer}

\title[Title]{Title}
\subtitle{\vspace*{0.5cm}{Subtitle}}
\author[ABC]{ABC\\[5mm]{\footnotesize \textbf{Supervisors:}\\Prof. QWERTY\\Prof. DEF GHI\\Prof. Jklmno Pqrst}}
\institute[UniversityXYZ]{}
\date[Today]{Today's date}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you are using the font switch `\footnotesize` for multiple line information inside a group and didn't ended the paragraph before leaving the group, so the wrong value for `\baselineskip` gets applied. You need `\author[ABC]{ABC\\[5mm]{\footnotesize \textbf{Supervisors:}\\Prof. QWERTY\\Prof. DEF GHI\\Prof. JKLMN OPqrst\endgraf}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why, but if you add `\\` to the end of the last professor it fixes the problem.

```
\author[ABC]{ABC\\[5mm]{\footnotesize \textbf{Supervisors:}\\Prof. QWERTY\\Prof. DEF GHI\\Prof. Jklmno Pqrst\\}}
```

Comment: It doesn't really solve it, but hides it; as soon as you add some text in the new line the problem reappears. The reason of the problem as well as a possible solution can be found in my comment to the question. If you want to, you can add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unnecessary pair of curly braces around the names of the professors. Removing these braces resolves the problem.

Comment: Those are required for enforcing the footnotesize

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using \hphantom to add space between names.

```
   \author[ABC]{ABC\\[5mm]{\footnotesize \textbf{Supervisors:}\\Prof. QWERTY\\Prof. DEF GHI\\ \hphantom\\ Prof. Jklmno Pqrst\\}}
```